# Find file or directory in whole directory structure

Tags: bash, directory, find

How can I find a file with a specific name in bash. I want to search through the whole system. I tried with find, but that only work through one level.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, `find` by default traverses all available levels:

```
sudo find / -mount -name 'myfilename'
```

If you have a separate home partition, or a encrypted home, or a secondary hard drive, you may want to list their mount points too, next to `/`, for example

```
sudo find / /home/enzotib /media/data -mount -name 'myfilename'
```

The `-mount` option is needed to avoid to traverse mounted filesystems. Among these there are `/proc`, `/dev` and `/sys`, that is convenient to skip.

An alternative to traverse all files, avoiding only these last three paths is

```
sudo find /!(proc|sys|dev) -name 'myfilename'
```

Comment: to find all files starting with "my" do:
find . -name my\\*   (bash would interpret the star if there were no slash)